# PHP Query invalid result

Tags: php, mysqli

I apologise if the title is confusing, but when I run the page with the code below and enter an email not found in the database, on the webpage I get `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\login.php on line 72`. Instead of it saying this, I want it to give an error that the email is not registered.

```
    <?php
session_start();//session starts here
if(isset($_SESSION['adminName'])||isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    header("Location: welcome.php");//redirect to login page to secure the welcome page without login access.
}
?>



<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<style>
    .login-panel {
        margin-top: 150px;

</style>

<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Sign In</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="login.php">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group"  >
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" type="password" value="">
                            </div>


                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="login" name="login" >

                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                          <!--  <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a> -->
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>

<?php

include("database/db_conection.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $user_email=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['email']);
    $user_pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['pass']);

    $encrypted_password = password_hash($user_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);


    $query = $dbcon->query("SELECT user_pass FROM users WHERE user_email='$user_email'"); 
    $passwordValue=$query->fetch_object()->user_pass;

    if (password_verify($user_pass,$passwordValue)){
        echo "Success!";
    }else{
        echo $encrypted_password;
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Error!</strong> Email or password entered was incorrect!</div>";
    }




    /*$check_user="select * from users WHERE user_email='$encrypted_email' AND user_pass='$user_pass'";

    $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run))
    {
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";

        $_SESSION['email']=$user_email;//here session is used and value of $user_email store in $_SESSION.

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
    }*/
}
?>
```

This is the code found in my login.php file. The php code within the comment isn't part of the web page, I will be removing it later.

Comment: What is line 72? ```$dbcon->query``` will return ```FALSE``` if the query fails for some reason (which will cause the subsequent line to throw an error). Can use ```$dbcon->error``` to help figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Line 72 is `$passwordValue=$query->fetch_object()->user_pass;`

Comment: Then yeah, you have an error in your query. Use ```print $dbcon->error;``` to print out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I make it so if there is no such email listed in the database, it outputs a certain bit of code

Comment: ```$query->num_rows()``` will return a number for the amount of rows that get returned. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @MasterOdin That is.... amazing. I used an if statement to find if the results brought no rows, and if it did, it would state that you typed an invalid email!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<style>
    .login-panel {
        margin-top: 150px;

</style>

<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Sign In</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="login.php">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group"  >
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" type="password" value="">
                            </div>


                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="login" name="login" >

                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                            <!--  <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a> -->
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>

<?php

include("database/db_conection.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $user_email=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['email']);
    $user_pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['pass']);

    $encrypted_password = password_hash($user_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);


    if ($query = $dbcon->query("SELECT user_pass FROM users WHERE user_email='$user_email'") == false) {
        echo "The email doesn't exist in the DB";
    } else {
        $passwordValue=$query->fetch_object()->user_pass;

        if (password_verify($user_pass,$passwordValue)){
            echo "Success!";
        }else{
            echo $encrypted_password;
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Error!</strong> Email or password entered was incorrect!</div>";
        }




        /*$check_user="select * from users WHERE user_email='$encrypted_email' AND user_pass='$user_pass'";

        $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($run))
        {
            echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";

            $_SESSION['email']=$user_email;//here session is used and value of $user_email store in $_SESSION.

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
        }*/
    }
}
?>
```

I've added an if statement that checks if the query is false, if it's false it will echo that the email doesn't exist in the database, as you wanted, but if it exist, then you're fetched the password exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I used an if statement for the code: `$query->num_rows()` (credit to @MasterOdin for that) and if the number of rows equaled 0, then I echoed that you typed in an invalid email.

Ex.

```
if ($query->num_rows==0){
    echo "You typed an invalid email!";
}else{
    I further verified information here...
}
```